# Is it efficient to use colliders on UI canvas in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, performance, optimization

Basically I have a task where the player will be able to drag an object (as UI Image), and place it inside a bag (another UI image).

What's the best optimized way to do so? As I researched, I do not think that using colliders for images is the "best" way to do it. 
Additionally, I was thinking about  checking if the position of the image while dragging overlaps an element; however, I do think that would be performant as that would require checking the position on each frame instead of "OnTriggerEnter".

What would be the best way to implement such function?

Thanks & Regards,
HurpaDerpa

Comment: What specific problem do you anticipate that's leading you to avoid using colliders? Did you try it, or your position checking method, to evaluate whether they meet your needs? Gobs of successful games run great with hundreds of colliders or position checks each frame. Do you have measurements that suggest that your game will struggle with this?

Comment: This looks to me like premature optimization.